# df.plot seems not to work in Pandas?

Tags: matplotlib, pandas, plot, anaconda

I am a python beginner. I meet an issue that I cannot do the plot function. But I have no idea how to fix it?

I am not sure if I miss something in my steps.

**The environment:**
win 7
Anaconda 2.1

**Code:**
    In [1]:

```
import pandas as pd
In [2]:

df = pd.read_csv("0103.csv")
In [3]:

df.plot()
Out[3]:
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xde49eb8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using ipython notebook.

If it is the case, executing `%matplotlib inline` should solve your problem.